# How to get "zero downtime" on HAProxy with a load balancer configuration?

Tags: heartbeat, haproxy

The scenario is, I have two web servers both are running Nginx on it. Also I have configured HAProxy after the LB (load balancer) for both the servers.

I've checked with Heartbeat, but no luck to make downtime count "zero". I want some application which will switch to secondary server instantly when primary server goes down, in other words it should not give any downtime.

Answer (score 2):

You should read about **High Availability** and **Fault Tolerant** systems.

From your description you have a High Availability configured in Active-Passive mode, withing this scenario you will **not** get zero downtime. As the application has to start on the second server when it fails on the primary server.

Unless you application is Active-Active wise then you might get the zero-downtime or close enough.